# Integration Test fails in jenkins with embedded mongodb

Tags: mongodb, jenkins, integration-testing

I ran my integration test locally, this works fine. But when try running jenkins, it fails. 
This integration test contain embedded mongodb. The integration test is below:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class MongoDbSpringUnitTest {

    @Autowired
    PriceRepository priceRepository;

    @Test
    public void testSavePriceMongoRepo() {
        priceRepository.deleteAll();
        Price price = priceRepository.save(new Price("1234productId", 24.5f));

       // System.out.println("id : "+price);
        assertEquals(0,24.5f, price.getCost());
        assertNotNull("id is autogenerate", price.getId());
    }
```

getting below error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'priceController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'priceRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'priceRepository': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mongoTemplate' while setting bean property 'mongoOperations'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/mongo/MongoDataAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'mongoTemplate' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoDbFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/mongo/MongoDataAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoDbFactorySupport]: Factory method 'mongoDbFactory' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'embeddedMongoServer' defined in class path resource 

[org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/mongo/embedded/EmbeddedMongoAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo.MongodExecutable]: Factory method 'embeddedMongoServer' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: this version does not support 32Bit: Version{3.5.5}:Windows:B32
```

above error show that embebbed db server cannot installed on 32 bit machine. I am not sure jenkins only support 32-bits. I am using jenkins 2.164.2.

The full code is present in below github:
https://github.com/ranjit5311/MicroServiceCode

Please let me know to resolve this issue.

Thanks,
Ranjit Kumar

Comment: looking at the error, it show that embedded mongo db version is 3.5.5. This version does not support 32-bit. Is this issue with jenkins version?

Answer (score 0):

After installing new version of Jenkins 2.164.3, resolved this issue.